# A proxy can interfere with detection of a browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, proxy, browser-detection

I'm having trouble with the `browser detection`.

In my website, i applied one plugin (Wordpress) to detect and reject some browsers, showing one upgrade image. Also, i placed the meta tag to force `IE` render to its edge version.

However, my client insists that his browser (`IE11`) been detected as `IE6`!

He uses a proxy, and i wonder if that is the problem to detect the browser correctly.

Is that possible?

Comment: If your browser detection works on the client side, the no.

Comment: @FelixKling Exactly, I applied the rules and exceptions properly, but needed a suitable clarification to inform my client, even on something that seems absurd, as this assumption on the proxy.